# Amazon RDS: Is it possible to have more than 5 read replicas?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

The [FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#91) seems to suggest that you can't have more than 5 replicas. Is there any workaround?

Comment: The FAQ doesn't seem to suggest that, it says it very plainly. Perhaps you could outline why this isn't sufficient so suggested solutions apply to your use case.

Comment: Best to ask Amazon directly on their forums.  The alternative is to build your own database, though that can be an endeavor.

Answer (score 1):

No. Amazon only allows you to create up to 5 replicas, and need to be launched one by one.

If You need more than 5 you can create a Master-slave configuration using EC instances, then you can have as many replicas as you want.